# SignalR hub not loading into Website if Hub having ref param API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

We are having SignalR hub like,if we have API with ref or out param SignalR hubs are not loading in to Website,

If i removed this "ref or out" param type it working fine.

And I am getting the below error if i access "Signalr/hubs" in browser

Expression of type 'System.Int32&' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Int32' of method 'Int32 test(Int32 ByRef)'

Hub Code:

public class TestCommHub : Hub
{

public void test(ref int intVal)
        {
            intVal = 0;
        }

}

Can anyone help to proceed this.

Comment: Why would you want to use ’ref’?

Answer (score 1):

The methods you write in C# in the Hub class are supposed to be available to be called from JavaScript. That will be done though a JavaScript proxy. Most cases the generated proxy, unless you manually define yours. ([about the proxy](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy))

JavaScript will simply not understand the C# `ref` and `out` parameters.

However, SignalR will serialize your complex object parameters into JSON so you can use it in JavaScript.